# Show vectors form an orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

[image]

[image]

I'm new to this particular topic and have been working through these tutorial questions.

For part $c.)$ I need to show vectors $u$ and $v$ form an orthogonal basis and then use that basis to form an orthonormal basis by normalising each vector.

I've begun with using the dot product for $u$ and $v$, such that $1.2$ + $3.1$ = $2.3$ = $6$, which is not equal to 1. And from my understanding this needs to be equal to 1 to be considered orthonormal?

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: You are taking inner product of $u$ and $v$ w.r.t the standard inner product, not the given inner product.

Comment: Are you referring to the inner product as defined in part $b.)$?

Comment: There is only one inner product in this question. For c) also you are supposed to use the inner product given in b).

Comment: Read the question carefully. Orthogonal means that the relevant inner product is **zero**!

Comment: @copper.hat I'm trying to, I'm just not sure about the process. I've attempted to sub the values of $u$ = $(1, 3)$ and $v$ = $(2, 1)$ into the inner product given in $b.)$, which I did get 0 for that.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm just not sure about the next step in finding the orthonormal basis.

Comment: An orthogonal basis is one such that each distinct pair of vectors has inner product zero. An orthonormal basis is an orthogonal basis such that each element has norm one. Note however, that the norm of $x$ is given by $\langle x , x \rangle$. So all you need to do is divide by the length (computed appropriately).

Comment: @copper.hat Yep, I got you now. I was able to prove they had an orthogonal basis and an orthonormal one. But, let's say I wanted to use the inner product from $b.)$ to express something like $w$ = $(1,1)$ as a linear combination of this orthonormal basis, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Broadsword93 The advantage of an orthonormal basis $u_1,u_2,...$  is that you can express any $x$ directly as $x = \langle u_1,x \rangle u_1 +  \langle u_2,x \rangle u_2+...$. (You should convince yourself why this is true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be orthogonal means $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$. In this case $\langle u,v\rangle=2(2 \cdot 1)-2\cdot 3-1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 3=0$ so the are orthogonal with respect to this inner product.

A unit vector is a vector $x$ such that the norm (ie. length) $||x|| = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} = 1$. For a set ot vectors to be orthonormal means they are all orthogonal  to each other and all unit vectors. Again using the inner product given we can calculate that $\langle u,u \rangle = 2(1 \cdot 1)-3 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 3 = 5 \neq 1$ so it's not a unit vector.

We can however find a unit vector in the same direction as $u$ if we scale $u$ by the reciprocal of it's length, so $(1/||u||)u= u /||u|| = u / \sqrt{5} = (1/\sqrt{5},3/\sqrt{5})$ and we can see that this is a unit vector because inner products are bilinear, so in particular for some scalar $k$ then  $\langle kx,y\rangle = \langle x,ky\rangle = k\langle x,y\rangle$. In this case $\langle u/\sqrt{5},u / \sqrt{5} \rangle =  (1/\sqrt{5})^2 \langle u,u \rangle = (1/\sqrt{5})^2 5 = 5 / 5 = 1$ so $u / ||u||$ is a unit vector. You can calculate this directly from the inner product formula as well. Similiarly $v / ||v||$ will be a unit vector, making $u / ||u||$ and $v / ||v||$ orthonormal with respect to this inner product.

Comment: Should be $\langle u,u \rangle = 2(1 \cdot 1) - 3 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 3 = 5$, not $7$.